# Determination of pixels which are included in the loop's bounds

Tags: c#

This program works with Median filter. I need help with fixing the code. It applies to the line

```
if ((diffX > -1) && (diffY > -1)...
```

...in the `MedianOfArea` method. It would be better if the pixels, which are included in the loop's bounds, would be determined initially. This solution helps to avoid checking every time. Can you help me with fixing it?

```
namespace Recognizer
{
    internal static class MedianFilterTask
    {
        public static double[,] MedianFilter(double[,] original)
        {
            var filter = new double[original.GetLength(0), original.GetLength(1)];
            var lengthX = original.GetLength(0);
            var lengthY = original.GetLength(1);
            for (var x = 0; x < lengthX; x++)
                for (var y = 0; y < lengthY; y++)
                    filter[x, y] = MedianOfArea(x, y, original, lengthX, lengthY);
            return filter;
        }

        public static double MedianCount(ref double median, List<double> pixelsFields)
        {
            pixelsFields.Sort();
            var countPixels = pixelsFields.Count;
            if (countPixels % 2 == 0)
                median = (pixelsFields[countPixels / 2 - 1] + pixelsFields[countPixels / 2]) / 2;
            else
                median = pixelsFields[countPixels / 2];
            return median;
        }

        public static double MedianOfArea(int x, int y, double[,] original, int lengthX, int lengthY)
        {
            var pixelsFields = new List<double>();
            double median = 0;
            for (int areasX = -1; areasX < 2; areasX++)
                for (int areasY = -1; areasY < 2; areasY++)
                {
                    var diffX = x + areasX;
                    var diffY = y + areasY;
                    if ((diffX > -1) && (diffY > -1) && (diffX < lengthX) && (diffY < lengthY))
                        pixelsFields.Add(original[diffX, diffY]);
                }
            MedianCount(ref median, pixelsFields);
            return median; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate directly on `diffX` (and `diffY`) and use `Min` and `Max` to set the ranges to loop over:

```
using System; 

int startX = Math.Max(0, x-1);
int endX = Math.Min(lengthX, x+2);
int startY = Math.Max(0, y-1);
int endY = Math.Min(lengthY, y+2);
for (int diffX = startX; diffX < endX; diffX++)
    for (int diffY = startY; diffY < endY; diffY++)
        pixelsFields.Add(original[diffX, diffY]);
```

Comment: I am grateful for your feedback, but now I have an error "The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You need to include System. I have added the line for that.